# React: addEventListener() returns error when called inside of useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

How can I add an event listener inside a `useEffect()` hook?

I'm using `useRef()` to target the nav element, then selecting all the link decendants. I'm then trying to add an event listener to those link elements  but I am getting an error.

Here's part of my component code:

```
let navRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    let links = sideDrawerRef.current.querySelectorAll('ul li a');

    links.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('hay');
    });
  });

<nav ref={navRef} >
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm getting the following error:

> links.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: Can you console.log(links)? Whats the output?

Comment: [`querySelectorAll(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList`, you'll have to loop through it and add listeners to each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than adding an event handler, consider delegating event binding to React via the `onClick` prop instead.

Doing so will simplify your component implementation:

```
let navRef = useRef();

const onClickLink = () => {
    console.log('hay');
}

<nav ref={navRef} >
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" onClick={onClickLink}>Link A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick={onClickLink}>Link B</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also, to add a few notes on your current code to explain some of the issues;

The `querySelectorAll()` method [returns a `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Return_value). To add click event handlers to all selected nodes, you must iterate each and add the event listener one-at-a-time:

```
let links = someAnscestor.querySelectorAll('ul li a');
for(const link of links) {
    /* Add click to currently iterated link node in NodeList result */
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('hay');
    });    
}
```

Additionally, the way `useEffect()` is being used here will cause the effect to be run every time the component renders. [Adding `[]` as the second argument to `useEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) will cause the effect callback to run once on startup which would be better suited here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I only run when the component first mounts");

    return () => {
        console.log("I run when the component is unmounted");
    }    
}, []); // <-- [] causes effect to run once
```

Comment: I'm going with eventHandler route to dry up my code a bit. The issue was related to NodeList, so I ran it through a for loop and called my function with each iteration. Works as expected now. Thanks for good answer.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)